# swap priority -2

Tags: swap

Using Ubuntu 16.04.
/proc/swaps indicates a priority of -2

`~$ cat /proc/swaps
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sdb3               partition   8263676 0       -2`

I have seen documentation saying the lowest priority can be -1 or 0, but not -2
So, is this something that needs to be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The priority is only important when there are more than 1 swap locations and then indicates an ordering between those swap locations.  So no it needs no attention unless you changed it yourself.

It is likely we NOW use -1 through 32767 and -2 used to be a valid number.

[Ubuntu Essentials 11.04](https://books.google.nl/books?id=V6IwEXysIEYC&pg=PT324&lpg=PT324&dq=/proc/swaps%20priority%20-2&source=bl&ots=QAqfltqDRB&sig=ACfU3U3XbrNHQGP84UdhZdSMIe17MBYU-g&hl=nl&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj176T6xJLpAhWKyKQKHa9lCJQQ6AEwCHoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=%2Fproc%2Fswaps%20priority%20-2&f=false) has -1 and -2 in their examples. [The manual page for 16.04, 18.04 and 20.04](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man2/swapon.2.html) do not state a range. The [generic Linux man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/swapon.8.html) claims it needs to be between -1 and 32767.

Comment: That claim is a lie, because I'm not specifying priority anywhere and yet one of my swaps is set to `-2`. So weird, something does that. I feel like a long time ago, even I recall setting stuff to that.

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/a2468cc9bfdff6139f59ca896671e5819ff5f94a